# find closest values between sublists with threshold

Tags: python-3.x, sublist, closest

I have a function for calculate closest value between sublists.
But i need to find only one value for each sublist, considering the threshold.
What can i do?

```
eee=[[22,27,28],[23,18,38]] 
www=[[30],[20]]

xx1=[]
for ee, ww in zip(eee, www):
    for w in ww:
        xx=[]
        for e in ee:
            cc = abs(e - w)
            if -7 <= cc <= 7:
                xx.append(e)
    xx1.append(xx)
print(xx1)
```

The expected values ​​could be:

```
[[28],[18]]
```

Comment: How does the result this program differ from what you expected?  What *did* you expect?

Comment: I expect this result [[28],[18]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `www` variable is a list of lists rather than a list of integers, each of its sub-lists can potentially hold more than one value even though there is only one value in each sub-list in your example. If there can indeed be more than one value in each sub-list in `www`, I would suggest that you use `itertools.product` to produce all the combinations of each item in the corresponding sub-lists of the two lists, and then use the `min` function with a key function that returns the distance between each pair of values to find the item in each sub-list of `eee` that's closest to any item in the corresponding sub-list in `www`:

```
from itertools import product
from operator import sub
[min(product(e, w), key=lambda p: abs(sub(*p)))[0] for e, w in zip(eee, www)]
```

This returns:

```
[28, 18]
```